# Wrong strlen output

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code in C:

```
char a[55] = "hello";
size_t length = strlen(a);
char b[length];
strncpy(b,a,length);
size_t length2 = strlen(b);
printf("%d\n", length);          // output = 5
printf("%d\n", length2);         // output = 8
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Use `size_t` for string lengths instead of `int`.

Comment: I did but output is still the same.

Comment: It would be, but in general it's incorrect to use a plain (signed) `int` for string lengths and array/object sizes. `size_t` is unsigned (so no -1 length objects) and is guaranteed to be the correct size for your platform (on 64-bit systems `size_t` will be 8 bytes while `int` might only be 4, which is sure to cause problems eventually). Also, to print `size_t` types, use `"%zu"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it has to be 'b [length +1]'
strlen does not include the null character in the end of c strings.

Comment: need to add `b[length] = '\0'` as well.

Comment: ..or use `strncpy(b,a,length+1)` as long as it's known that there's a null character at (or before) `a[length]`

Answer (score 4):

You never initialized `b` to anything. Therefore it's contents are undefined. The call to `strlen(b)` could read beyond the size of `b` and cause undefined behavior (such as a crash).

Comment: ...and as it's contents are undefined, there may happen a 0 in the array. And it breaks the strlen.

Comment: Sry I missed a line of code, b has been initialized now but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Ronnie Slack: Can you show the initialization? (comment it so that we know the answers that have been posted are still relevant)

Comment: sry, still relatively new to stackoverflow.

Comment: So then can someone show me an example snippet that would make this example work?

Comment: @Ronnie Slack: Everyone was new at some point. :) You can edit your question. There's an `edit` button below the tags.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is not initialized: it contains whatever is in your RAM when the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

For the first string a, the length is 5 as it should be "hello" has 5 characters.

For the second string, b you declare it as a string of 5 characters, but you don't initialise it, so it counts the characters until it finds a byte containing the 0 terminator.

**UPDATE**: the following line was added after I wrote the original answer.

```
strncpy(b,a,length);
```

after this addition, the problem is that you declared b of size length, while it should be length + 1 to provision space for the string terminator.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am such a C noob. haha

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that you need to allocate `strlen(a)+1` characters for `b` to be able to hold the whole string.

They've given you a set of parameters to use for `strncpy` that will (attempt to) cover up the fact that it's not really suitable for the job at hand (or almost any other, truth be told). What you really want is to just use `strcpy` instead. Also note, however, that as you've allocated it, `b` is also a local (`auto` storage class) variable. It's rarely useful to copy a string into a local variable.

Most of the time, if you're copying a string, you need to copy it to dynamically allocated storage -- otherwise, you might as well use the original and skip doing a copy at all. Copying a string into dynamically allocated storage is sufficiently common that many libraries already include a function (typically named `strdup`) for the purpose. If you're library doesn't have that, it's fairly easy to write one of your own:

```
char *dupstr(char const *input) {
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
    if (ret)
        strcpy(ret, input);
    return ret;
}
```

[Edit: I've named this `dupstr` because `strdup` (along with anything else starting with `str` is reserved for the implementation.]

Answer (score 0):

Actually char array is not terminated by '\0' so strlen has no way to know where it sh'd stop calculating lenght of string  as as
 its syntax is int strlen(char *s)-> it returns no. of chars in string till '\0'(NULL char)
so to avoid this this we have to append NULL char (b[length]='\0')

otherwise strlen count char in string passed till NULL counter is encountered